# TypeError: unhashable type when Pass NSDictionary using XMLRPC in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, odoo-8, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I am currently using xmlrpc in ios app and pass NSDictionary in XMLRPCRequest then it will give me following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type
```

My code as below:

```
 NSDictionary *dict = @{@"offset" : @(2),
                      @"limit" :@(1),
                     };

NSMutableArray *argslogin = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:keyDatabase],     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:uid], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:keyPassword], @"demo.partners",@"search_read",dict,nil];

XMLRPCRequest *requestlogin = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverlogin]];

[requestlogin setMethod:methodlogin withParameters:argslogin];
```

So anyone know this type error how to solve in ios then please help me because i have spent many hours to find out solution for that but not get any solution.

Comment: chek your `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:keyDatabase]` and `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:keyPassword]` type contains data or not, if yes check what the type of data and all other are working perfectly

Comment: can show `NSLog` of `argslogin`?

Comment: hello Piyush,5 min i will give you log

Comment: Hello piyush,<__NSArrayM 0x600000250470>(
demo_messag,
9,
test123,
demo.partners,
search_read,
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000001afe0>(
{
    limit = 1;
    offset = 2;
}
)

Comment: Hello Anbu,
i checked NSUserDefaults values and passed all values.
My Log values as below:
<__NSArrayM 0x600000250470>( demo_messag, 9, test123, demo.partners, search_read, <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000001afe0>( { limit = 1; offset = 2; } )